# Can't get React + socket.io to work on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to set up a simple socket.io echo server on Heroku using Express and React. The server returns the React site from the `build` folder, then listens for incoming messages using `onAny()`. Everything works fine locally, but when deployed to Heroku none of the client-emitted messages are going through after the connection has been established.

I've used [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets) as well as create-react-app and [this Medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/build-a-real-time-chat-app-with-react-hooks-and-socket-io-4859c9afecb0) as my starting points, and did make sure to turn on http-session-affinity as the Heroku guide said to.

Currently, the React client is set up to emit a fixed message through the `onclick` handler of a `<span>`.

Here's the contents of `server.js`:

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express()
    .use(express.static('build'))
    .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

const io = socketIO(app);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('Client connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Client disconnected'));
    socket.onAny((type, data) => {
        console.log('Received:');
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('echo', data);
    });
});
```

And here is the client-side React hook that establishes the connection and emits the messages, where I replace `[app-name]` with the Heroku app name:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

const NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT = "newChatMessage";
// const SOCKET_SERVER_URL = 'localhost:3000';
const SOCKET_SERVER_URL = 'wss://[app-name].herokuapp.com/sockjs-node';

const useChat = (roomId) => {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const socketRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        socketRef.current = socketIOClient(SOCKET_SERVER_URL, {
            query: { roomId },
        });

        socketRef.current.on(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, (message) => {
            console.log(message);
            const incomingMessage = {
                ...message,
                ownedByCurrentUser: message.senderId === socketRef.current.id,  
            };
            setMessages((messages) => [...messages, incomingMessage]);
        });

        return () => {
            socketRef.current.disconnect();
        };
    }, [roomId]);

    const sendMessage = (messageBody) => {
        console.log('sendMessage()');
        socketRef.current.emit(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, {
            body: messageBody,
            senderId: socketRef.current.id,
        });
    };

    return { messages, sendMessage };
};
```

Comment: Curious, does it actually connect on heroku, meaning you see the socket connect on heroku? Have you tried to change the URL to http vs wss ? Socket.io will determine this for you, so it should just be http or https

Comment: @proxim0 I do see the socket connection in Chrome's "Network" tab, and on page load it gets 5 messages with types "log-level", "hot", "liveReload", "hash", and "ok". I'm guessing these are the standard establishing-the-connection messages. No others appear when I click the `<span>` to emit.

I did try http/https initially before trying wss, and didn't get any further with them.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this in the end? I have basically the same problem and used the same medium article as a basis for my chat coincidentally. Here's my question for more details if you're inclined:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337349/react-socket-io-chat-app-not-working-on-heroku