# React/Socket.io chat app not working on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I have a chat app I made using React for the frontend, DRF for the backend and I also have a node.js server within the React app for socket.io The issue is that the chat doesn't work basically (it works fine locally). When a message is sent it's not emitted and only shows up when I refresh since it's then pulled from the DB instead. I have gone through many threads on here for this issue but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My server:

```
const server = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
    },
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT = "newChatMessage";

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log('Client connected')
    // Join a conversation.
    const {roomId} = socket.handshake.query;
    socket.join(roomId);

    // Listen for new messages
    socket.on(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, (data) => {
        io.in(roomId).emit(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, data);
    });

    // Leave the room if the user closes the socket
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        socket.leave(roomId);
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, (error) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Hook I made for the frontend:

```
const NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT = "newChatMessage"; // Name of the event
const SOCKET_SERVER_URL = `https://<my-react-frontend>.herokuapp.com`;

export const useChat = () => {

    const socketRef = useRef();
    const {messages, setMessages, activeConvo, headerConvo, reloadSideBar, setReloadSideBar} = useActiveConvo()
    const roomId = activeConvo
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useChat useEffect ran')
        // Creates a WebSocket connection
        socketRef.current = socketIOClient(SOCKET_SERVER_URL, {
            query: {roomId},
        });

        // Listens for incoming messages
        socketRef.current.on(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, (message) => {
            const incomingMessage = {
                message: message.body,
                created_by: localStorage.getItem('currentUserID'),

            };
            console.log('messages set in useChat useFfect')
            setMessages((messages) => [...messages, incomingMessage]);

        });

        // Destroys the socket reference
        // when the connection is closed
        return () => {
            socketRef.current.disconnect();
        };
    }, [roomId]);

    // Sends a message to the server that
    // forwards it to all users in the same room
    const sendMessage = (messageBody) => {
        socketRef.current.emit(NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE_EVENT, {
            body: messageBody,
            senderId: socketRef.current.id,
        });
        const fetchContents = {
            message: messageBody,
            created_by: localStorage.getItem('currentUserID'),
            convo_id: activeConvo ? activeConvo : headerConvo

        }
        fetch(`https://<my-drf-backend>.herokuapp.com/api/save-message/`, authRequestOptions(('POST'), fetchContents))
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(setReloadSideBar(reloadSideBar + 1))
            .catch(error => console.log(error))


    };

    return {messages, sendMessage};
};
```

The issue in most of the threads appeared to be either still using the localhost url on the frontend or not using process.env.PORT in the server but it's still busted after fixing that. I also saw someone mention in another thread that the folder structure was the issue so I tried having the server file in the root of the react app and  having it in it's own folder under "src", no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone faces this same issue, I solved it by putting the server in a separate app on heroku